# Clockwork with a multi-tenant setup

Tags: clockwork

My app uses postgres schemas to implement multi-tenancy. So for a table like `users`, each tenant actually has it's own `users` table -

- `public.users` (default)
- `foo.users`
- `bar.users`
- ...

As a side note, it implements multi-tenancy using the [apartment gem](https://github.com/influitive/apartment)

The clockwork gem allows you to read events from a database table, with the use of it's `sync_database_events` method. For example, it can read events from a `scheduled_jobs` table/model:

```
sync_database_events model: ScheduledJob, every: 1.minute do |model_instance|
  rake model_instance.name
end
```

By default this reads from `public.scheduled_jobs`, but each one of my schemas will have it's own `scheduled_jobs` to read from.

Is there a convenient way to have it loop through all my tenants?

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing a very similar thing with the difference that I'm using Apartment and MySQL not Postgres.  Apartment is very, very powerful but it feels poorly documented at best.  Here was how I approached this:

```
if Rails.env.development?
  every(1.day, '3am.job -- Daily Job', :at => '03:00') do |job|
    User.delay.crawl
    Search.delay.crawl 
  end
elsif Rails.env.production?
  every(1.day, '3am.job -- Daily Job', :at => '03:00') do |job|
    SiteApi.usernames.each do |username|
      Apartment::Tenant.switch!(username)
      User.delay.crawl
      Search.delay.crawl        
    end
  end
end
```

The magic happens in my Rails.env.production? block.  SiteApi is an API that talks to my master database of users and gets back an array of usernames.  It then calls Apartment::Tenant.switch!(username) to switch the tenancy context to the right user. It then calls the functions that I need to run on each tenant.

You should note that I am also making use of the Apartment Sidekiq extension for delay.

I suspect this conceptual leap is what you're looking for.